# Best place for testing data in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm developing testing app and I would like to have testing data there. I'm not sure what's the best place where to put array of testing players. Right now it's inside my reducers like this:

```
let players = [
    {
        id: 0,
        nickname: 'Player 1'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        nickname: 'Player 2'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nickname: 'Player 3'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nickname: 'Player 4'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        nickname: 'Player 5'
    }
];

export default function(state = players, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'REMOVE_PLAYER':
            let players = state;
            players = players.filter(function( obj ) {
                return obj.id !== action.player.id;
            });
            return players;
        case 'ADD_PLAYER':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    nickname: action.new_player
                }
            ];
    }

    return state;
}
```

Is there any better place where can I put it? Maybe separate file, or inside default function?

Comment: The testing players is the default state for reducers or not. Its probably ok to keep it in the same file as long as it is being used by the reducer itself

Comment: Is the players list the initial state of your reducer or just mocked data for testing purposes ?

Comment: @ArnaudChrist It's initial state for testing, data will be loaded from database, but that's long way till I get there... I'm using testing arrays in more than one reducer, so that's why I'm asking if this is the best place.

Comment: It its just a temporary thing that you need to add for test, you don't need to create a separate file for it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri All right thanks you. I think you confirmed, what I thought :)